# VS2012 Debugger can watch variables from third party reference only once

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I am sorry for this vague title, but I have trouble describing in 1 clear sentence my issue, hopefully some answers will help me both with the solution and the knowledge surrounding it.

So!

I have this small form application which I use to test the new Dynamics 2013 Web Services. I added the third party reference Microsoft.Xrm.sdk.dll to my references. (I named this specific dll, but this occurred to me with other third party dlls, I just wanted to give a bit more context)

Here is a very small sample of code of a line I execute in this application :

```
RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse response = (RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse) m_OrgProxy.Execute(raeRequest);
Console.Write(response);
```

The type RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse's full type is {Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages.RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse} .

Basically, the first time I debug my application, I am able to watch this variable , hover over it, etc.

```
+       response    {Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages.RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse}    Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages.RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse
```

On the other hand, let's say I stop the application, restart and break at the same place, I will not be able to watch this variable.

```
response             The name 'response' does not exist in the current context
```

If I restart VS2012, then the first time I debug it, I will once again be able to inspect the variable, but all times after that, nope.

I checked the Modules window, and both times, working or not, the symbols will not be loaded for Microsoft.Xrm.sdk.dll. (which I find a bit surprising, I kinda expected to see symbols the first time.)
I am running in debug, non-optimized code, I cleaned my solution and disabled my add-ins, which did not change anything. Does anyone have any idea what is going on, what I need to look into to figure this out?

I messed with the debugging options like Enable Just My Code, Enable .Net Framework source stepping and JIT for Managed, but none of these options solved the problem.

Thank you!

Comment: This is a hunch. Try disabling the visual studio hosting process.  Right click on project -> properties, debug tab, unchecked the bottom check box which talks about the hosting process

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not fix the issue :-(

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would have liked to understand exactly why this occurred, but using Visual Studio 2013 solves this issue.

Comment: Please update your original question with additional information instead of posting an answer.